# Did I install 2 versions of spamassassin on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, spamassassin

Now I have been struggling to install spamassassin.
As a new user of linux I'm trying to make sense of information the Ubuntu system gives me.
Command `getent passwd` returns among others:

```
debian-spamd:x:113:123::/var/lib/spamassassin:/bin/sh
spamd:x:5001:5001::/var/log/spamassassin:/bin/false
```

Does this mean there are more installations, also a Debian version which is not good since it runs on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu is a Debian derivative.  The 'debian-spamd' user was created by the package manager.  This is the user id that should be running spamassassin.  Install the package managed version, it will save you no end of grief.

To debug start spammassin from the command line with the command `spammassassin -D`.  You may need/want some additional Perl packages.  It also helps to install the `spamc` package.

Comment: Aha, debian-spamd wouldn't be strange then. But there still are two users: debian-spamd and spamd, isn't this strange?

Comment: The command 'spamassassin -D' gives: 
"No command 'spammassassin' found, did you mean:
 Command 'spamassassin' from package 'spamassassin' (main)
spammassassin: command not found"
What do you mean by "install the package managed version"? apt-get install spamassassin spamc?